# Can Thunderbird be configured to display the full newsgroup names?

Tags: thunderbird

Here's an example of how Thunderbird shortens the names:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know whether this still works in the current version (don't have a TB installed on this machine), but it used to be that you go into the about:config (Edit -> Preferences -> Advanced -> General -> Config Editor), then search for the line

```
mail.server.default.abbreviate
```

And change it to *false*. And you should be good.

Comment: omgoodness!!! You rock! Thank you! :-)

Comment: By the way, in my version (7.0.1), I got to the config editor via: Edit -> Preferences -> Advanced -> General (tab) -> Config Editor...

Comment: @dharmatech Now the config editor is opened via Edit -> Preferences ->  Config Editor… at the bottom of the right pane.